# Enable game access to a user that did the payment with PayPal, IPN

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

My website contains a game and if users want to continue playing after level 3, I'd like that they pay 10 euro. I'm inclined to use a simple PayPal button for the payment. After reading the official PayPal documentation, it seems that it is possible to do the following:

- The PHP session variable `$_SESSION['user_id']` identifies uniquely a player (this comes after a Login in the game and info about each user is stored in a database).
- User `$_SESSION['user_id']` clicks on the "Buy Now" button, gives payment details and pays.
- Using IPN (Instant Payment Notification), PayPal sends a POST request to my server containing the result of the payment and at this time one can know the value of `$_SESSION['user_id']` corresponding to the payment done.

This should be something easy to do but the fact is that I'm completely lost in PayPal documentation which seems to be too vast, to me. I know, maybe I'm not the best developer.

I think there should be also some code already done for this very simple scenario.

Then, assuming that the users pays and that PayPal then calls paypal_ipn.php, which POST attribute allows me to verify that a user with a given `$_SESSION['user_id']` payed?

Comment: @DainisAbols maybe you're right but the game is fine. It's probably me that I have no experience with PayPal. Please tell me something constructive.

Comment: I'm really having no clue why this post is getting so negative votes. If someone can explain that would be helpful to me.

Comment: Questions asking us to ***recommend or find*** a book, tool, software library, ***tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic*** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @Epodax I indeed described the problem I had and what was done so far. Well, I found the answer to myself as you can see below without the help of Stackoverflow.

Comment: Asking for a guide stil makes your question off-topic even if you do describe your problem, look at it like this: Just because you are wearing your seat belt while driving, doesn't make it okay to go over the speed limit in your car.

Comment: Ok @Epodax I modified the question.

Answer (score 0):

After digging more and more on PayPal documentation, I found the "custom" field in the HTML "Buy Now" button. So the answer is just to add

```
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<? echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>">
```

in the form of the PayPal button.